# Reading a list of records SQLite - Need advice

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some data (Student info), and my app should be able to read and display these student records in a `UITableView`.

I need to know the following;

1. ) Where should i store these student records ? I know that i could store them in the SQLITE query browser (in the MAC) but, when users install the app on the device how are they going to read the student records from (because the iPhone doesn't have a query browser for someone to enter the records) ?

Comment: I guess CoreData http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html could be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating Database in SQLITE save that Database, which gives you file with extension **.sqlite** then drag and drop that **.sqlite file** in to **Resources folder of you application program in XCODE** and then install in you iPhone It will work. and you can use Sqlite using iPhoen

Comment: Thank you, may i also ask you where to find sqlite query browser on the Mac (i am unable to locate this)

Comment: Just press Command + Space and Type SQLite Browser, It will show on list if it install on you MAC

Comment: There is another alternative for that is to download SQLite addons for mozila firefox

Comment: Command + Space doesn't show SQLite Browser in the search. Does that mean that i have to install SQLite ? I thought it comes by default

Comment: No you need to install it. You can download it from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ and install it in your Mac

Answer (score 2):

when you will create a sqlite database, you have to store it in your application folder only just like any local image for app like Default.png or icon.png.... and when you run your app on device the sqlite database also will be loaded together with the application....sqlite database will be stored as a file with extension .sqlite onle...copy it in your app...it will just execute just fine.....when you write coding like "Select *..." or "INsert into..." or "delete from...." remember to give the correct name of the sqlite file copied in your app...

Comment: you can create sqlite database using SQLITE manager.... there is an app also but you can only download a trial version of it with features only....another way is to open FIREFOX browser and search SQLITE manager add-on for firefox on google.... you can find a manual there only how to use it after installation, though its kinda easy to use